# Which std-functions call the user implemented version of the swap function?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

In order to decide if it makes sense to support a custom version of swap in the post C+11x age I wanted to know which std-functions call swap and 
will they still benefit from a user implemented version even in the presence of a move-constructor and move-assignment?

Comment: You could always profile the code and see if swapping is a hotspot.

Comment: I think it's more important where the Standard Library *requires* a type to be swappable (than to where your implementation of the Standard Library actually calls `swap`). This you can easily find out by searching the Standard (or a draft) for the term "swappable".

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I don't think the standard library will call your swap function,</strike>

The standard library will call your implementation of `swap` in those places where it requires that the type is *swappable*, for example in the implementation of `std::pair<>::swap`. Besides this, other code might also use your `swap` to implement their own `swap` function. For those cases, if you have implemented the move constructor and move assignment, the standard implementation of `std::swap` *should* but is not required (AFAIK) to use the move-constructor/assignment.

The implementation of `swap` for a type that already implements the move operations is a three line function, so I would go ahead and implement it anyway:

```
void swap(mytype& lhs, mytype& rhs) {
   mytype tmp(std::move(lhs));
   lhs = std::move(rhs);
   rhs = std::move(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the default implementation for Cx11? So no need to implement it that way =)

Comment: @Thorsten [utility.swap] contains no *required* implementation (and no "default" one; I'd even say there are no default implementations in the Standard, only exemplary implementations or required effects).

Comment: @DyP: MoveConstructible does not require the presence of a move constructor or that it is used. A copyable type is move constructible (a movable but not copyable is also move constructible). A perfectly valid implementation of `std::swap` for copyable types in a C++11 compiler is the implementation of `std::swap` from the C++98 version of the same compiler.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Oh, you're right, I keep forgetting that `MoveConstructible` and `MoveAssignable` are weaker than the corresponding `Copy`* requirements (the latter imply the former).